# Location based service with normal image

Tags: android, geography, rasterization

We have an image for a park which has been rendered like this:

[image]

Now we want to add some geographic service based on the data: building an Android Application with the following features:

1. Display the map with drag/move/zoom operation.
2. Add overlays like markers,lines on the map.
3. Show the location of the user(by gps or network service).
4. Calculate best routes between two points.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I know we have to do the georeference job, but I am not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you must first georeference the image. Once you have it georeferenced, standard mapping libraries will be able to display it and support pan/zoom etc. If your image is large, you can create tiles and display it. See [Google Maps API for Android Tile Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay)

For calculating routes, you will need road network data. You will need to digitize the road network from this image and use a routing library. You can take inputs from the user, have the routing library calculate the route and display it on the map with your image using lines. See [Google Maps API for Android Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes).

Comment: Once I got a geogerferenced image, I will generate tiles for certain zoom, but how to make the image geogerferenced is what I required.

Comment: Try this http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/advanced_georeferencing.html